# Prevent Special Characters - jQuery Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So I have this simple form validation on a text input.

Been doing some Googlin' and can't find how to limit any special characters - meaning I want to prevent the use of anything besides alphanumeric characters.

I want to include it in this function... anyone?

```
if (!campaign_name || !'^[a-zA-Z 0-9]+$'){
    //alert('Please enter campaign name');
    // Do nothing
    return false;
};
```

Comment: you shouldn't use OR with NOTs it will almost always evaluate to true. you probably ment &&

Comment: You also need a regex. you've written one as a string, regex is denoted as /^[a-zA-Z 0-9]+$/ or via new Regex

Comment: You can use function like String.match or Regex.test to compare against your created regex.

Comment: Not sure i exactly get that...

Comment: None of this has anything to do with jQuery FYI.

Comment: !campaign_name is also bad form. You should compare its type to undefined to avoid some other issue with you truth test.

Comment: @j_mcnally, There is a `$` in the regex -> jQuery. :)

Comment: `!` is bad form?? Was taught this way...and see if used elsewhere A LOT. What are you suggesting? `campaign_name == ""`?

Comment: if (typeof campaign_name !== "undefined" && campaign_name !== null) is usually safer, it depends on the context. If you are testing for existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/.test(campaign_name)){
    // error...
}
```

Comment: @MikeBarwick. It's a regex function. [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: Gotya...so this would be the ideal IF function: `if (!campaign_name || /[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/.test(campaign_name))`?

Comment: @MikeBarwick. no, `!campaign_name` will be true for `0`, you need `campaign_name === "" || ...`

Comment: Oh okay. thought that was essentially the same thing...it works that way.